# How to use beforePopState in next js 13?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have a usecase where i need to catch the user if he/she clicks on backbutton of browser. In NextJs 12 we can use beforePopState method of router but i couldn't find equivalent of that in NextJs 13.